# DatePicker and LocalizationProvider not rendering on MUI core v4.12.3 with MUI Lab v5.0.0-alpha.57

Tags: reactjs, date, material-ui

I am attempting to use the DataPicker and LocalizationProvider with MUI v4.12.3. Here are the package JSON imports

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"@material-ui/core": "4.12.3",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.57",
"@mui/material": "^5.12.2",
"@mui/styles": "^5.6.2",
"@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.8.0",
"dayjs": "^1.11.8",
```

In the file, it is importing at:

```
import { DatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/lab';
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
```

With usage such as:

```
return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}
     <DatePicker [Properties here] />
    // Entire component
    </LocalizationProvider>
)
```

However, the page does not render unless Localization is removed (it encases the entire component). When that is removed, the rest of the page renders except for the DataPicker component.

The current version of MUI must stay as v4.12.3 (Same for React v17). Is the lab import not correct? Are any other imports incorrect for MUI v4?

After further research, I used the following imports:

```
import { DatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
```

However, AdapterDateFns has no import from `@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs` is an error I am receiving. This is even though it told me to import from there after trying to do it via MUI lab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your were close to the correct solution. Use `@mui/x-date-pickers` to get `Date Picker` component and `LocalisationProvider`.

And if you want to use `Date-Fns` date library for date you need to get AdapterDateFns, it's under `@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns`

```
import { DatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
```

But in your package JSON imports I see you use `dayjs` library. So, maybe you just need adapter for it, if so, import `AdapterDayjs`

```
import { DatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
```

Comment: Thank you, the first import with the AdapterDateFns worked. I might've been using AdapterDayjs wrong when I tried the second import. Also could have something to do with my limited React version.